# How likely is that my ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 application will be cracked?

Tags: openssl, aes, rsa, diffie-hellman, c

I am using the following chain in my cipher: `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`

I am wondering if there's a weak chain in this cipher that might allow my application's communications to be cracked?

I'm new to cryptography and don't understand every detail. (I did Google them each, and they are saying it's secure but you guys have deeper knowledge and it's why I came to you.)

Comment: There is no publicly know vulnerabilities for that setup. That being said the question is really low quality, too specific to be helpful for someone else

Comment: the setup is too typical to need more specificity, i'll set up openssl to take the default action for this cipher suite, no deviation from the norm or different setups than the one OOTB.

Answer (score 3):

> How likely is that my ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 application will be cracked?

It is very unlikely that an application using the cipher will be cracked because of a weakness in the cipher. It might though be cracked by a bad implementation of this cipher, by a wrong use of this cipher or by anything outside of this cipher - like trying to protect information using the cipher which can be grabbed by the attacker as plain data before encryption or after decryption.

In summary: the usage of a specific cipher alone does not say much about the security of the application. Instead the full application has to be audited including the environment where it is used and how it is used.

Comment: thanks! I'm planning to go the default OpenSSL way to use this cipher, basically the default key exchange method and encryption and everything. Would you say this would be secure?

Comment: @PajeetGurav: these are not enough information about implementation, environment and use of the application. For example: a typical problem is to implement the authentication wrong by not checking the certificate properly and thus making the application open to man in the middle attacks. How exactly the certificate validation is done is not covered by the cipher itself and may be specific to the unknown use case.